# Gaussian copula, t-student copula and Frank copula, seem are the same?

Tags: copula

I read about Gaussian, t-student and Frank copula. Gaussian copula is similar to Frank copula where both of them cannot model tail dependencies. Also, I read that, t-student copula is symmetric tails dependency. However, when the degree of freedom of t-student is high, then we get Gaussian copula. My question is, how does t-student becomes a tails dependencies while it is similar to Gaussian copula? And what is the differences between these functions? Finally, general Gaussian density is similar to Gaussian copula, so why do we need Gaussian copula?

Any help please to understand the difference between such common used copula functions?

Comment: You can check what they looks like at: Normal vs Frank vs T: http://www.assetinsights.net/Glossary/G_Normal_Copula.html They are different.